# Publish C# application with Access database and Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, crystal-reports, publish

I developed a C# Windows Forms application with Access database and Crystal Reports reporting. After publishing it, when i try to install it i get this error message.

[image]

Translation of the error message:

> An unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will be shut down immediately.

I googled this error message and i didn't get the solution.
Ps: i tried to install it in my own computer not in the client computer and i get the same message.

Comment: what is the second like of the code which usually tells you what the error is

Comment: this is the error message and when i click continue the application will be installed and works properly. i want to know why this error is appearing

Comment: This may be a missing library which you have referenced but not included in the published file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the database file status to Data file in publish settings/Application files